# Using the console and tkinter interface at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I have three lists to fill out for the calculation(summons, division..), so I have to use the console. I'm trying to create a tkinter interface on which I will enter inputs to have the result. I don't know how to use the lists with tkinter

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: Please consider posting your actual code and whatever errors you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, how to use the tkinter interface to display the result ?

k =int(input("give the value of k \n"))
n = int(input("give the value of n \n"))
def function(k,n):
Z=[]
for x in range(k):
F=float(input("give the value of F"+str(x+1)+"\n"))
H=float(input("give the value of H"+str(x+1)+"\n"))
v=F/H
Z.append(v)
s=0
for i in range(len(Z)):
s+=float(Z[i])
return (1/n)*s